# "No-throw dereferencing" of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I write code in C++ which uses a `std::unique_ptr u` to handle a `std::string` resource, and I want to dereference `u` so that I can pass the `std::string` to a call of the `std::string` copy constructor:

```
std::string* copy = new std::string( /*dereference u here*/ );
```

I know that `new` or the `std::string` copy constructor could throw, but this is not my point here. I was just wondering whether dereferencing `u` could already throw an exception. I find it strange that `operator*` is *not* marked `noexcept` while the `std::unique_ptr` method `get` is actually marked `noexcept`. In other words:

```
*( u.get() )
```

is `noexcept` as a whole while

```
*u
```

isn't. Is this a flaw in the standard? I don't get why there could be a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: How is `*(u.get())` `noexcept`? Can't `u.get()` return `nullptr`?

Comment: @BartoszKP how is returning `nullptr` related to `noexcept`?

Comment: @BartoszKP: Um, the reference on cplusplus.com says that get is noexcept... As far as I know, dereferencing a nullptr won't throw an exception. Anyways, I check if( u ) before I try dereferencing it.

Comment: @Slava Yeah, you're right. What I meant is that `operator*` can verify that you're dereferencing a null pointer and throw if yes, whereas `get()` shouldn't do that. But that still doesn't make sense as `operator->` is `noexcept`...

Comment: cppreference.com says `operator*` may throw, let's see what standard says

Comment: @Slava [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) it says it may throw.

Comment: @BartoszKP yes sorry, my misunderstanding, so looks like yes it may check if pointer not null

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`unique_ptr::operator*()` could involve a call to an `operator*()` overload for the type you're storing in the `unique_ptr`. Note that the type stored in a `unique_ptr` need not be a bare pointer, you can change the type via the nested type `D::pointer`, where `D` is the type of the `unique_ptr`'s deleter . This is why the function is not `noexcept`.

This caveat doesn't apply to your use case because you're storing an `std::string *` in the `unique_ptr` and not some type that overloads `operator*`. So the call is effectively `noexcept` for you.

Comment: could it be marked as `noexcept(noexcept(*std::declval<T>()))` ?

Comment: @RyanHaining That might work for the fringe case I described, but what if `T` is a pointer? Now you've got a `nullptr` deference in the `noexcept` specification.

Comment: I didn't realize that operator* can be so complex under the hood as compared to *( .get() ). Very interesting, thanks for elaborating on that!

Comment: if `T` is `nullptr_t`, the expression still isn't actually evaluated, I don't think I understand your point

Comment: @RyanHaining The nullptr dereferencing part was about when you were value initializing the pointer, before you modified the comment to `declval`, and I'm not sure doing that even in an unevaluated context is OK. Assuming the `T` in your `noexcept` spec is from `unique_ptr<T>`, then you might be trying to deference a type that doesn't overload `operator*`. And if `T = unique_ptr<U>::pointer`, which let's say is `U*` then you're checking whether that type has a `noexcept` constructor (I think). That noexcept spec doesn't accomplish what you want in all cases.

Comment: ohh yes I see my mistake now.

Comment: Also, not making `operator *` `noexcept` allows implementations to diagnose the UB (in case the stored pointer is null) by throwing an exception in debug mode.